# Changing System Property in Java

Tags: java, policy, securitymanager

I'm trying to study JINI library, and found example of simple programm. Programm is here:

```
package book.basic;
import net.jini.core.discovery.LookupLocator;
import net.jini.core.lookup.ServiceRegistrar;
import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

/**
 * UnicastRegistrar.java
 */
public class UnicastRegister {
    static public void main(String argv[]) throws RemoteException {
        new UnicastRegister();
    }
    public UnicastRegister() throws RemoteException {
        LookupLocator lookup = null;
        ServiceRegistrar registrar = null;
        System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
        try {
            lookup = new LookupLocator("jini://localhost");
        } catch(java.net.MalformedURLException e) {
            System.err.println("Lookup failed: " + e.toString());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        try {
            registrar = lookup.getRegistrar();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Registrar search failed: " + e.toString());
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Registrar search failed: " + e.toString());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("Registrar found");
// the code takes separate routes from here for client or service
    }
} // UnicastRegister
```

If I run this application, then throws exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException:
>   access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:4160"
>   "connect,resolve")    at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
>     at
>   java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
>     at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1051)
>     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:574)     at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)  at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:425)   at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:241)   at
>   net.jini.core.discovery.LookupLocator.getRegistrar(LookupLocator.java:328)
>     at
>   net.jini.core.discovery.LookupLocator.getRegistrar(LookupLocator.java:286)
>     at book.basic.UnicastRegister.(UnicastRegister.java:26)   at
>   book.basic.UnicastRegister.main(UnicastRegister.java:12)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

I created policy file "policy.all" and put it in home directory:

[image]

this file contains text:

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Next, I triend to pass this file as argument in command line:
-Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=/policy.all,
More like this -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=./policy.all
I did this in idea:
[image]

I get next compile error:
[image]

If I tring to set policy file directly like this:

```
System.setProperty("java.security.policy","file:/policy.all");
System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
```

it produces no result, and I get java.security.AccessControlException again.